Trouble enabling Apertium APY for MediaWiki
I have successfully installed Apertium APY on my AWS server running on localhost:2737 and tested the various endpoints using cURL to validate the installation per https://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Apertium-apy#Installation
I have installed the MediaWiki MLEB per instructions at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_Language_Extension_Bundle and verfied all modules are loaded in the Special:Version pages of my wiki
I then modified my LocalSettings.php to point Apertium to my localhost with the endpoints I am using locally and verfied using the following code snippet:
$wgTranslateTranslationServices['Apertium'] = array(
    'url' => 'http://localhost:2737/translate',
    'pairs' => 'http://localhost:2737/listPairs',
    'key' => null,
    'timeout' => 3,
    'type' => 'apertium',
);

# Private api keys for machine translation services
$wgTranslateTranslationServices['Apertium']['key'] = 'abcdef123456';

However when I try any of the Translation features I do not see my active languages for which I installed the language word pairs - sudo apt-get install apertium-en-es
I need a little help on enabling the Apertium features within MediaWiki and LocalSettings.php
My Apertium modes directory is populated and works with cURL calls for listPairs, etc...
total 44K
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  895 Jul  6  2022 spa-eng_US.mode
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  892 Jul  6  2022 spa-eng.mode
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.1K Jul  6  2022 eng-spa.mode
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   87 Aug 29 15:09 README
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  128 Aug 30 05:15 spa-tagger.mode
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   63 Aug 30 05:15 spa-morph.mode
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Aug 30 05:15 spa-gener.mode
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  151 Aug 30 05:15 spa-disam.mode
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  188 Aug 30 05:15 spa-disam-tagger.mode
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4.0K Sep  8 14:50 ..
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Sep  8 14:50 .

Any assistance is greatly appreciated as I have exhausted all the available MediaWiki help sections on installation and configuration. I feel I am close to a solution and would welcome any assistance.
I tried all the steps found in the Help and Configuration sections of the MediaWiki Extensions section for Translate, Universal Language Selector, cldr, and Babel. I still can't seem to make it work.
